# How to retrive datas from mysql database and show those data on leaflet map?

Tags: php, mysql, leaflet

Getting error like-

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

```
 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here I intended to loop through the JSON objects and, for each,  add a marker to a marker cluster group named city.

```
  

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var map = L.map('map').setView([22.5726, 88.3639], 4);
 L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=dVhthbXQs3EHCi0XzzkL',{
   attribution:
   '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
 }).addTo(map);
 var marker = L.marker([22.5726, 88.3639]).addTo(map);
 var city = L.markerClusterGroup();
  var Points = $.getJSON("get_location.php", function(data) {      
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var new_location = new L.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
   var place = data[i].place;
   var marker = new L.Marker(new_location, {
     title: place
   });
   var message = 'Place name: ' +place;
   marker.bindPopup(message);
   city.addLayer(marker);

      if (data[i].latitude < SWlat) {SWlat = data[i].latitude}
      if (data[i].longitude < SWlng) {SWlng = data[i].longitude}
      if (data[i].latitude > NElat) {NElat = data[i].latitude}
      if (data[i].longitude > NElng) {NElng = data[i].longitude}

 }
  });
  Points.done(function() {
  locSW = new L.LatLng(SWlat, SWlng);
  locNE = new L.LatLng(NElat, NElng);
  mapBounds = L.latLngBounds(locSW, locNE);
  map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
  });
 map.addLayer(city);
</script>
```

Still getting error message in console and the marker points are not showing in map. Can anyone kindly help me in this?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong at first sight. Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes the error was  Uncaught TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function
    at (index):20. Why is it coming?

Comment: That's a symptom of the MarkerCluster plugins not being loaded. See e.g. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/a320380620e0142cf17b774267948c2ea9280674/example/marker-clustering.html#L11-L13

Answer (score 2):

Some issues require your attention:

1. Add plugin markercluster
2. Add plugin jquery

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3. You should not use the location variable to create a location because the location variable is the same as the location variable in the plugin, so it causes an error. Instead you can rename another variable such as new_location variable.

```
var new_location = new L.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
```

4. You can refer to my code here

> link:
>
> ```
> https://codepen.io/Bossken26/pen/vYZgJpG?editors=1000
> ```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map' style="width: 900px; height: 700px;" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var map = L.map('map').setView([22.5726, 88.3639], 4);
  L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=dVhthbXQs3EHCi0XzzkL',{
    attribution:
    '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
  }).addTo(map);
  var marker = L.marker([22.5726, 88.3639]).addTo(map);
  var city = L.markerClusterGroup();
  // var Points = $.getJSON("get_location.php", function(data) {      
  var data = [{
    "Time": "2015-03-08T15:43:47.220Z",
    "latitude": "13.4596",
    "longitude": "92.7483",
    "depth": "40.08",
    "mag": "4.6",
    "magType": "mb",
    "nst": "NA",
    "gap": "123",
    "rms": "0.82",
    "id": "us10001ll4",
    "updated": "2015-05-28T00:48:38.040Z",
    "place": "194km N of Bamboo Flat, India"
  }, {
    "Time": "2015-03-11T19:14:37.510Z",
    "latitude": "36.4926",
    "longitude": "71.1417",
    "depth": "88.97",
    "mag": "4.4",
    "magType": "mb",
    "nst": "NA",
    "gap": "74",
    "rms": "0.61",
    "id": "us10001lne",
    "updated": "2015-05-28T00:48:42.040Z",
    "place": "40km WSW of Ashkasham, Afghanistan"
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var new_location = new L.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
    var place = data[i].place;
    var marker = new L.Marker(new_location, {
      title: place
    });
    var message = 'Place name: ' +place;
    marker.bindPopup(message);
    city.addLayer(marker);
    //   if (data[i].lat < SWlat) {SWlat = data[i].lat}
    //   if (data[i].lng < SWlng) {SWlng = data[i].lng}
    //   if (data[i].lat > NElat) {NElat = data[i].lat}
    //   if (data[i].lng > NElng) {NElng = data[i].lng}
  }
  // });
  // Points.done(function() {
  // locSW = new L.LatLng(SWlat, SWlng);
  // locNE = new L.LatLng(NElat, NElng);
  // mapBounds = L.latLngBounds(locSW, locNE);
  // map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
  // });
  map.addLayer(city);
</script>
```

[image]

Good luck! ^^

Comment: After doing what you said I am getting a refference error. I have edited the post you can see it there. How to resolve this?

Comment: Attention:
`1. You must add the plugins in order, especially the MarkerCluster must be below the Leaflet`
2. You initially declare the map variable then below you also have to use the map variable. Map.addLayer(city) not mymap.addLayer(city)
`3. To declare L.LatLng(lat,long) you need to new it. `
Ex: var new_location = new L.LatLng(lat, long);
`Good luck!`

Comment: when I am giving directly the datapoints then only those Place markers are showing. otherwise not.

Comment: Above code is missing <div id='map' style="width: 900px; height: 700px;" ></div>. I checked the code above it still works fine, you can check the console and debug the code in browser DevTools . Maybe it's wrong variables SWlat, SWlng, NElat, NElng, locSW, locNE, mapBounds....